# JQuery Mobile css doesn't work after ajax call even with (.listview("refresh"))

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

The page lost its JQMobile CSS after call Ajax, even when I had added:

```
$("#idlist").listview("refresh");
```

in my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var display= $("#displaydata");
    function displaydata()
{
    $.ajax({
        crossDomain:true,
        type:"GET",
        data:"lihat==suku",
        url:"server.php",
        success: function(data){        
        display.html(data);

        }
    });
}

displaydata(); });
```

I have called data from PHP, here's my PHP code:

```
    if(isset($_GET["lihat"])=="suku")
{
    $tampil = mysql_query("select * from deskripsi");
    echo"<ul id='ul' data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-filter='true' data-filter-placeholder='Cari Suku Besar...'>";
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($tampil))
    {
        echo"<li>$r[suku]</li>";    
    }
    echo"</ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

In you **PHP** code, build a **HTML** string and then finally echo the string value.

Like this:

```
if(isset($_GET["lihat"])=="suku") {
    $tampil = mysql_query("select * from deskripsi");
    $string = "<ul id='ul' data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-filter='true' data-filter-placeholder='Cari Suku Besar...'>";
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($tampil)) {
        $string .= "<li>$r[suku]</li>";    
    }
    $string .= "</ul>";
    echo $string;
}
```

And after appending the response data, in your ajax success function add the code below:

```
$("#idlist").listview().trigger("create");
```

Enjoy...

Answer (score 1):

Press `f12` and see wheather you are getting any error message. Are you sure the response is received correctly?

You need to success function as below. `html()` will simply replace all the content in the div so you gonna have to re-add `<ul></ul>` tags again.

```
    success: function(data){ 
        var tempString = "<ul data-role='listview'>";
        tempString += data;
        tempString += "</ul>";
        display.html(tempString);
    }
```

Try and refresh the listview as below

```
$("#idlist").listview();
```

`$("#idlist").listview("refresh");` seems to work for existing listview not for the one we built from the scractch.

Comment: dont' wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function() {});` instead you need to wrap inside `$(document).on('pageshow', function(){       });`